# Special signs such as æøå always stands with lowercase even though forced by strtoupper

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I am collecting the following names from the database and using `strtoupper` to make them upper case:

```
ADFæRD


FORRETNINGSFORSTåELSE


INTERNT


KOMMUNIKATION


KOMPETENCEMåLING


KULTUR


LEDELSE


MOTIVATION


PRODUKTER

PSYKOLOGI


SALG & PERFORMANCE


SERVICE


SYSTEMER
```

As you can see every character works however the special characters like ÆØÅ is always lowercase.

Is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: `strtoupper` has no idea about non-ascii chars. You want `mb_strtoupper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mb_strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php), example :

```
$s='adfærd';
echo mb_strtoupper($s, 'UTF-8');
```

outputs

> ADFÆRD

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [mb_strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php)

> Returns str with all alphabetic characters converted to uppercase.
>
> [...]
>
> By contrast to strtoupper(), 'alphabetic' is determined by the Unicode
> character properties. Thus the behaviour of this function is not
> affected by locale settings and it can convert any characters that
> have 'alphabetic' property, such as a-umlaut (ä).

Example:

```
$str ='adfærd';
echo mb_strtoupper($str , 'UTF-8');
```